# Lost Out of Sky - Local Usage (India) or Typo

Tags: expressions, dialects, subcontinental-english

I was reading a news [story about a jet crash in the UK](http://www.rushlane.com/hawker-hunter-jet-crashes-12159268.html) from a site hosted in India, and I believe the author may also be from there.

In it, I saw the sentence:

> The jet which appeared to have lost out of sky while performing looping-the-loops, smashed...

In the US, the phrase "lost out of sky" would either be "run out of sky" or "lost altitude".

My question is, is this an common or accepted expression in Indian English or even a more localized dialect, "to lose out of [something]," or is it merely a typo on the part of the author?

Comment: I suspect this is a literal translation from another Indian language but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am from India as well and we simply follow standard UK English.

There is no known local phrase like "lost out of... ".

The author of the article most probably had no ulterior meaning hidden behind the words and did simply meant that the jet disappeared; got lost out of the sky.

Comment: "have lost in the sky" would have been better in my opinion.

Comment: @Man_From_India perhaps, but if that's what the author of the article chose to go with, so be it.

Comment: 'I am from India as well and we simply follow standard UK English.' Are you claiming that the 'Indian English' tag is unnecessary? I've come across quite a few usages originating in the Subcontinent that I'd insist are certainly not standard English.

Comment: @Edwin I completely agree with you. Due to the British influence, it seems, they (we) try to follow BrE and even in University exam rules one will find some BrE construction is regarded correct whereas their American counterparts are considered wrong. It might be one indication. As for your nonstandard usage, you are correct. Lots of local languages and different cultures surely have some impact on English spoken here. Some are actually incorrect or as you said nonstandard as far as correct standard English is concerned. I suspect if this one is not.